# Is there relation between vector valued RKHS and interpolation space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, soft-question, definition

Vector valued RKHS which is covered extensively in the book "Pick Interpolation and Hilbert function spaces" . On the other hand interpolation space which is defined in the wikipedia link:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space. My question are these related somehow? Can we define both under the same framework? I got this idea from limited understanding of the paper:
http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2008-77-263/S0025-5718-07-02096-0/S0025-5718-07-02096-0.pdf

Any clarification would be appreciated.